# how to make two elements bottom align in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

one ImageView and three TextView in RelativeLayout.
what I want is make imageview and '6.4MB' TextView bottom align.
activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/screenshot"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/screenShot"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Video Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:textSize="23dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/videoName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="2021.05.19 · 5:11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#797675"
            android:id="@+id/recordDate"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
            android:layout_below="@id/videoName"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="6.4 MB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#797675"
            android:id="@+id/videoSize"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/screenShot"
            android:layout_below="@id/recordDate"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot" does not work.
anyone can help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android:layout_alignBottom="@id/screenShot" does not work

Because You also have added `android:layout_below="@id/recordDate"`

If You will remove this `layout_below` property then `layout_alignBottom` will work as expected.

But when You will remove `layout_below`, then it may look strange. So You have to make changes according to that

**EDIT**

If You do not want to remove `layout_below`, then may be adding gravity to bottom will also work for You. As this will align the text to the bottom

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make is simple just replace code with this use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and use weightSum inside linearLayout. Remove redundant code and make it short.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/screenShot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/screenshot" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/videoName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:text="Video Name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recordDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:text="2021.05.19 · 5:11"
            android:textColor="#797675"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/videoSize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:text="6.4 MB"
            android:textColor="#797675"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:text="6.4 MB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#797675"
    android:id="@+id/videoSize"
    android:layout_below="@+id/screenShot"
    />
```

I didn't get it completely what you are asking for but If you want to put `6.4 MB` of text below ImageView you need to change your TextView attributes.